# Java LinkedList remove method does not remove element properly

Tags: java, linked-list

Notice how it doesn't remove them in a sensible manner. It's like it shifts everything in the array but isn't that something only ArrayLists do?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create a list of integer to Test our logic.

    LinkedList<Integer> halfOf = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    halfOf.add(1);
    halfOf.add(2);
    halfOf.add(3);
    halfOf.add(4);
    halfOf.add(5);
    halfOf.add(6);
    halfOf.add(7);
    halfOf.add(8);


    halfOf.remove(0);
    halfOf.remove(1);
    halfOf.remove(2);

    System.out.println(halfOf);
```

**Gives output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: I expected: [4,5,6,7,8]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`LinkedList`'s `remove` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-int-) effectively shifts indices of elements beyond what is removed.

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

After removing index 0:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

After removing index 1:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

After removing index 2:

```
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Like for an `ArrayList`, you should keep track of indices you're removing.  The easiest way to remove multiple elements this way is to remove them highest index first.

Comment: The easiest way to remove multiple indices in this case, because they are consecutive, is to use `halfOf.subList(0, 2).clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`List.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)

> ... Shifts any subsequent elements to the left ...

This must be true for any class which implements the `List` interface, including both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` doesn't remove element from 0th index you can check by example, I too was facing such issue, you can use `array.remove(Object)` which removes element based on object hashcode much safer option.

```
boolean isRemoved=array.remove(0);
if(!isRemoved) {
    isRemoved = array.remove(array.get((int)(midIndex)));
}
```